# Term for when manufacturer uses less material

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for when a manufacturer removes a bit of material from the thing they are making to reduce cost? The image a have here is a drawbar lock. The circle and small square are not functional, the manufacturer just leaves out that amount of metal because it is not necessary.

[image]

Comment: **Retrenchment** or **economising**.

Comment: Trimming the product.

Comment: Yes, what @user358018 said. Note that trimming is not simply "omitting to add"; in your example, punching the cutouts is an additional manufacturing step. This could be as much to decrease overall weight as to save material. Weight is an _important_ detail when considering shipping, or for products like airplane seats.

Comment: How do you know that those pieces have been cut out to reduce cost and not, for example, for some aesthetic reason? (Or maybe it doesn't matter, if you're making that the assumption of the question in the first place.)

Comment: @Conrado thank you for supplementing my answer.

Comment: Also known as “cost-cutting measures”

Comment: To quote Mitch Hedberg, "The Kit-Kat candy bar has the name Kit-Kat imprinted into the chocolate. That robs you of chocolate! That's a clever chocolate-saving technique."

Comment: The Crunch bar is even more diabolical. The entire bar is sunken inside the parameter.

Comment: Reducing quantity may be called skimping.

Comment: @NuclearWang none so much as the [Aero™ chocolate bar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aero_(chocolate_bar)) although in Europe, the actual weight must be stated on the package.

Comment: It is well known that the strength of a material needs to be localised. Steel girders are often made as a lattice grid instead of with solid flanges - that can't be skimping because there is a required performance strength. If the part is stamped from a steel plate (as it appears to be in the image, rather than *machined*), and the spare metal recycled, it can reduce the manufacturing cost. It is not necessarily **skimping**. On the contrary, the reduced weight and hence transportation costs, actually benefit the end user.

Answer (score 1):

***Shrinkflation*** is the closest word I could come up with.

> **Shrinkflation:** In economics, *shrinkflation is the process of items shrinking in size or quantity, or even sometimes reformulating or reducing quality while their prices remain the same or increase*. The word is a portmanteau of the words shrink and inflation. [[Wikipedia]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shrinkflation)

Or if you spend less money (save money), or reduce costs, that's called ***[retrenchment](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/retrench)*** or ***[economising](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/economize)***.

Answer (score 1):

The correct word to use depends on intended context.

To reduce overall costs even if the reduction requires new manufacturing steps, use "economising".

If economising is a new demand because of economic factors (e.g., material costs have increased), use "retraction". This is probably the most applicable term to the picture shown in the question.

If the material removed is removed because the finished product doesn't require it and because the material being removed is detrimental to the product's purpose (e.g., flash--the excess metal especially around edges left behind by imperfect casting, forging, etc.), use "trimming".

Answer (score 1):

This video shows a drawbar and a drawbar lock in use.

https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=2kcDcMVdUOA

The speaker calls the cut-out notch “manufacturer prowess” (the piece is melted down and the material reused). The rectangular cut-out goes over the drawbar to keep it from rotating. The lock weighs about four pounds; at issue is a tractor pulling a trailer.

The term “skimping” is used in the video to refer to using insufficient material (too light-weight for the demands to be placed on it), but this particular drawbar does not involve skimping.

Comment: That video led to the question. I couldn't find "manufacturer prowess" anywhere, so I was wondering if the guy just made it up or if there was another term that was a better fit.

Comment: @Homer He created the phrase. He does explain it, though. It’s like manufacturer skill, for example, or inventiveness. A way to reduce cost without damaging the product.